# Как вызвать ассинхронную лямбду в C++?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine-4, unreal-engine, unreal-engine-5

Можно ли вызвать ассинхронную лямбду в С++ (или unreal)?

Вот пример псевдокода. Если убрать async и await строку то код работает и возвращает 11 в переменную res.

```
float res = async ([](float a, float b) {
    await Delay(2000);
    return (std::abs(a) + std::abs(b));
})(5,6);
```

Comment: В С++ нет асинхронный лямбд. А при работе с UE наверное стоит использовать предлагаемые фреймворком механизмы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно пониманию, вы хотите вызвать лямбду асинхронно, то вот вам простой пример как это сделать. Требуется компилятор, поддерживающий C++11 страндарт и выше.

```
// std::launch имеет 2 вариант запуска выбираете удобный 
// https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch
// Параметр запуска std::launch::async гарантирует асинхронность в общем случае.
auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, [](float a, float b) { 
     return (std::abs(a) + std::abs(b));
}, 5, 6);
```

[.get()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get) блокирует вызывающий поток, пока не исполнится вызываюший код
`auto result = f.get();` 
В вашем примере где вы хотите ждать какое-то время подойдет [wait_for()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for) + get() методы.

```
std::cout << "waiting...\n";
std::future_status status;
using namespace std::chrono::literals;
do {
     switch(status = f.wait_for(2000ms); status) {
         case std::future_status::timeout: std::cout << "timeout\n"; break;
         case std::future_status::ready: std::cout << "ready!\n"; break;
     }
} while (status != std::future_status::ready);
 
std::cout << "result is " << future.get() << '\n'; // 11
```